# Do I need to sign a class library (.Net dll) generated with Visual Studio with an EV code signing Certificate?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, code-signing-certificate

I'm about to compile a .NET 4.8 class library (dll) that will be used by a Windows app (exe) signed with EV CSC. I was wondering if there was any necessity or relevance to sign also the dll? Anyway, Visual Studio has deactivated the ClickOnce feature, as I don't compile an exe, but only a dll. So?